# Xcode Storyboard file was broken suddenly

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode is 10.1 and has been used for over 6 months. Before upgrading Security-Updates-2009-001 from App Store in MacOS X High Sierra 10.13.6, my Xcode quitted frequently and accidentally. Today, after upgrading the security path, it finally broke my Xcode and my Storyboard in projects suddenly as the images below.

[image]

It doesn't work even I checkout my Git to previous versions. It seems that the Xcode was something wrong inside, and so does my Simulators. The Xcode cannot launch any Simulators at all and always shows "Unable to boot simulator", no matter I launch it from Scheme Building or Launchpad.

I have been testing all solutions on boards to try to recover my Simulators and Storyboards, but it doesn't work. Does anyone can give me more assistance to solve it?

[image]

> Unable to boot the Simulator.

The broken Storyboard looks like this one.. and the Log text file shows

> Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. (Failure reason: IBAgent-iOS failed to launch): Failed to boot device iPhone 8 (E28478CE-81DC-4B16-A12E-16AA7086BE31, iOS 12.0, Shutdown) for context ...... The folder “disabled.plist” doesn’t exist. (Failure reason: The folder doesn’t exist.): The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory (Failure reason: No such file or directory).....

[image]

and it is useless to uninstall and re-install Xcode again and again from 10.1 to 10.0 and to 10.1 again

Comment: its hard to fix, but you can check the crash report of Xcode and look for something "clear" and change it in the storyboard xml content, also file a radar about this

Comment: After re-installed Xcode, the issue is still there. The Log.txt shows the content like this below 
"Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. (Failure reason: IBAgent-iOS failed to launch): Failed to boot device iPhone 8 (E28478CE-81DC-4B16-A12E-16AA7086BE31..... The folder “disabled.plist” doesn’t exist.

Comment: All Storyboard, XIB files are not readable and editable on iOS, watchOS, and tvOS projects, but only be fine on macOS projects.

Answer (score 2):

The below permissions are worked for me.

`sudo chmod -R 777 /private/tmp/`

Answer (score 1):

After trying again and again, I finally deleted all Xcode and re-installed Xcode 10.1 again and then changed the permission and ownership of the folder **/private/tmp** to ***777*** and ***root:wheel***, and it finally works back!! Storyboard and xib files are workable now.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66665

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue of **Command Line Tools** resetting it may fix up your problem...

Run `xcode-select --reset` in your terminal and tell me if it works for you : D

Comment: that does nothing

Answer (score -1):

I have spent more than 6 hours on this. Restarting the Xcode fixed it

Comment: OP already did that. They even reinstalled Xcode. It's explained in their question and comments.